# $(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2})^k = \epsilon$, solve for $k$

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms

I am currently reading a paper which states that if $k = O(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\log{\frac{1}{\epsilon}})$, then $(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2})^k = \epsilon$. However, I am unable to get the algebra to work out. Using logarithm rules, I get that $k = \frac{\log{\epsilon}}{\log({1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}})}$, but am unsure of where to go from here. What are the steps required to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Formally that doesn't make any sense, if one result is only a $O()$ then the other can't be exact, and in fact here you can't even conclude that the result of the exponentiation is $O(\epsilon)$. That said, $\log(\epsilon)/\log(1-\epsilon/2)=\log(1/\epsilon)/(\epsilon/2 + o(\epsilon))=O(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \log(1/\epsilon))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that what was meant by $\displaystyle k = O\left(\tfrac 1 \varepsilon \log\tfrac 1 \varepsilon \right)$ is $\displaystyle k = O\left(\tfrac 1 \varepsilon \log\tfrac 1 \varepsilon \right) \text{ as } \varepsilon\downarrow 0.$

If you have $k = \dfrac{\log\varepsilon}{\log\left(1 - \frac \varepsilon 2 \right)}$ you can first say that $\log\left( 1 - \frac \varepsilon 2 \right) \approx -\frac\varepsilon 2,$ since that's just using the tangent line to the logarithm function at $1$ as an approximation to the curve.
$$
\frac{\log \varepsilon}{\log\left(1- \frac \varepsilon 2 \right)} \approx -\frac 2 \varepsilon \log\varepsilon = \frac 2 \varepsilon \log\frac 1 \varepsilon.
$$